# What does DRG in Linux mean and what function it has

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, huawei-developers

I have found DRG module in HUAWEI Harmony OS open source on Linux. Could someone tell me the definition of DRG and how it works?
Here is the of code of the attached file (I can not post the code for it is too long).
It is used in the Linux kernel to schedule the CPU.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svfOd.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KcX3.jpg)

Comment: Do not link external images. Programmers should know not to open random links from random people. And it makes difficult to create an answer (we should type the original code). You have the code, so you can copy it as text (I'm assuming your link has a screenshot of code).

Comment: For some special reasons, I could not copy the code but gave a screen shot. Later, I will show you the code. thanks.

Comment: Valuable reading: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please edit and include properly formatted text for code, errors, data, etc.